# Why should company choose VB.NET over C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VB.Net vs C# debate](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1180/vb-net-vs-c-debate)

Are there any actual reasons why company should choose VB.NET over C#?

I work for a company which develops medical software and switched from VB6 to VB.NET several years ago. There were two reasons to switch to VB.NET but not to C# at that moment:

1. VB.NET is more similar to VB6 and it should make it easier for
   developers to switch to .NET world
2. VB.NET had a better support for COM than C#

The first reason is not serious as VB6 and VB.NET are two different worlds and there is no significant difference between switching from VB6 to VB.NET or C#. The second reason is not actual after C# 4 release.

Our company eventually switched to C# (and yes, we now have modules in VB6, VB.NET and C#; and even some modules in C++) because:
1. It is easier to find developers in C#
2. .NET world is C#-oriented: Visual Studio works better with C#, Resharper has better support for C#, etc.

I am just curious whether there are still some reasons for company to choose VB.NET over C#.

Comment: Possible duplicate/related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1180/vb-net-vs-c-debate, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/42894/would-a-programmer-knowing-c-and-vb-net-ever-choose-vb-net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mostly legacy reasons:

- Existing devs don't know C#
- Lots of existing VB6 / VB.Net code
- Hard to find C# devs locally
- Stuck on earlier versions of Visual Studio (which had better inlellisense for VB.Net)
- Prior investment in VB.Net tools (e.g. only having VB.Net version of Resharper)
- Liking VB.Net more than C#

Answer (score 2):

Developer background... I have that situation at my new job right now. I come from a C# background, but the others developers (2) that already worked in the company come from a VB.net background

Comment: Agreed, the companies I have worked for that used VB.NET over C# did so entirely because they had more developers already familiar with VB.NET when they decided to switch to .NET.